# Index of Razor loop items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

(Pretty new to Razor. The following is heavily pseudo-codified and extracted from my code. I may not have the correct terminology, or know exactly what parts are core versus custom code.)

I want to have access to the order/index of each item in the item of the for-loop. (i.e. in item #1 I can reference '1' and in item #2 I can reference '2' etc.) So I can use it SORT OF like this (I don't care **how** I get it, just **that** I get it):

item.cshtml:

```
@model myWidgetViewModel
<a href="foo" 
    @TrackingHelper.SetInfo(new ClickTrackInfo { 
        item = @Model.Name, 
        index= @Model.idx
    })
>
    @Model.Name
</a>
```

wrapper.cshtml

```
@model myWidgetViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model.myWidgetItems)
{
    @Html.Partial(item.View, item)
}
```

Conceptually, I'm trying to do accomplish like this:

```
@model myWidgetViewModel
@{int idx = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.myWidgetItems)
{
    @Html.Partial(item.View, item, idx)
    idx++;
}
```

But of course, this does not work (@Html.Partial only accepts 2 args).

Comment: You can change the model that partial expects, say have something like `myWidgetIndexedViewModel`, with two fields - `myWidgetViewModel model` and `int index`. Passing this from main view will be trivial then

Comment: why do you need the index in the partial view?

Comment: Did you try to add an public int property to myWidgetItem definition and set it in the foreach block just before calling @Html.Partial?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need the index. Most things can be easily accomplished with a template model view and using `@Html.EditorFor`, removing the need to self-index input names.

Comment: I have updated the post to show a better example of what I will be doing with the index in wrapper.cshtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to handle what you would like:

**1: Include a property on your partial view model**:

You will need to modify your partial view model whatever the type of *item* is to have a new property of type int called *WidgetIndex* and then you can do this:

```
@model myWidgetViewModel
@{int idx = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.myWidgetItems)
{
    item.WidgetIndex = idx;
    @Html.Partial(item.View, item)
    idx++;
}
```

...then, in your partial you can use it:

```
<div>@Model.WidgetIndex</div>
```

**2: Put it in a view bag** (note that you can call the property anything, not just *WidgetIndex*:

```
@model myWidgetViewModel
@{int idx = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.myWidgetItems)
{
    ViewBag.WidgetIndex = idx;
    @Html.Partial(item.View, item)
    idx++;
}
```

...then, in your partial you can grab it:

```
<div>@ViewBag.WidgetIndex</div>
```

**3: You can use ViewData:**

```
@model myWidgetViewModel
@{int idx = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.myWidgetItems)
{
    ViewData.Add("WidgetIndex", idx);
    @Html.Partial(item.View, item)
    idx++;
}
```

in partial:

```
<div>@ViewData["WidgetIndex"]</div>
```

**Suggestions**:

You can use IndexOf method instead of keeping a variable (note, I used the code from Solution 1 as an example):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.myWidgetItems)
{
    item.WidgetIndex = Model.myWidgetItems.IndexOf(item);
    @Html.Partial(item.View, item)
    idx++;
}
```

You can use RenderPartial instead of Partial for better performance:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.myWidgetItems)
{
    item.WidgetIndex = Model.myWidgetItems.IndexOf(item);
    @{Html.RenderPartial(item.View, item);}
    idx++;
}
```

Comment: More to it than that it seems:
Solution 1: 'Error: myWidgetItems does not contain a definition for Index'
Solution 3: 'Error: does not contain a definition for Partial (had some invalid arguments).'

Comment: I've used many of these methods in a number of MVC solutions.  I only copied your pseudo code, so let me try and clarify for you in the solutions.

Comment: I've updated my solutions and comments.  For solution 1, you need to add the Index property to the partial view model class for that to work.  Solution 3 has changed to use ViewData instead of what I had before.

Comment: Solution 1 worked 
(I had to explicitly convert idx.toString(). Not sure why it needs to a be a string). 
And I added 
public string Index { get; set; } to myWidgetItems.somethingSomethingBuilder.cs
Thank you!

Comment: You had to cast idx to string because you set your public Index property to type of string.  You would need to change "public string Index {get;set;}" to "public int Index {get;set;}" to avoid the cast.  Glad I could help and feel free to upvote/accept if you like it!

Answer (score 0):

Send a tuple to your partial

```
var args = new Tuple<myWidgetItemType, int>(item, idx);
@Html.Partial(item.View, args)
```

And then accept that as the model in your partial (note: you use var in your foreach loop so it is hard to tell the exact type of `myWidgetItemType`)

```
@model Tuple<myWidgetItemType,int>
```

In your exact scenario, it would look like this:

wrapper.cshtml

```
@model myWidgetViewModel
@{
    int idx = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in Model.myWidgetItems)
{
    var args = new Tuple<myWidgetItemType, int>(item, idx++);
    @Html.Partial(item.View, args)
}
```

item.cshtml

```
@model Tuple<myWidgetItemType,int>
<a href="foo" 
    @TrackingHelper.SetInfo(new ClickTrackInfo { 
        item = @Model.Item1.Name, 
        index= @Model.Item2
    })
>
@Model.Item1.Name
</a>
```

Comment: What is myWidgetItemType? I think it's an IList. But IList wants to know what kind of items it contains.

Comment: @DaveC426913 - Hover over the `var` in your `@foreach` loop. It is that type.

Comment: @DaveC426913 - If all you are really using is the name string, you can also simply use `Tuple<string,int>(item.Name,idx++)` and then in your item.cshtml page use `@model Tuple<string,int>` and then use `item = @Model.Item1, index = @Model.Item2` and after the anchor `@Model.Item1` again.

Comment: Im not really sure the complexity of a Tuple is the right course of action here,  See [Is using the new System.Tuple class bad design?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/124065/is-using-the-new-system-tuple-class-bad-design) for more information.  I think OP could do something that conveys more meaning to their code.

Comment: @JasonWilczak - "Complexity"? There is none, it is simply a holder for these types. Tuple is a lightweight container for a simple view model like this and it is going to be very readable with the explicit types.

Comment: There is complexity, there is additional cognitive load for Item1 and Item2, which conveys no real meaning to the code.  Additionally, your model now needs to be of type tuple, which would require any other consumers of the partial to utilize a tuple as well.  If this is desired, then simply adding a named property would convey a stronger meaning to any future maintainers of the code.

Comment: @JasonWilczak - Creating excessive view models is an anti pattern. If it is possible to simply add a property to a view model that can be an option, but now you have placed the requirement of adding that property to every view model which would be used in a view that makes this call. Cognitive load for .Item1 and .Item2 where the types are explicit and there are only 5 lines of code? You need to think of scale. If this were a larger view it *may* make sense to use a qualified model here, but it is just two properties. Don't overengineer yourself into bad habits.

Comment: @TravisJ I can understand your point of view.  In my opinion, and my experience, it is much easier to understand  named properties and types when writing/reviewing code over using generics.  OP already has a qualified model for their partial view, I see no advantage of using a tuple to solve their problem, but that is my experience.

Comment: @JasonWilczak - With the tight coupling from the view model to the partial there is basically no need for the partial anymore. It has lost any possible use anywhere else because it requires the view model from that one view to use. I see no reason to do that. And if that is required, this entire partial view is useless and should be simply refactored into the view.

Comment: @TravisJ I disagree.  OP could refactor their code to set a WidgetIndex property on the server side and completely mitigate that logic on the main view.  This would make the partial and it's view model reusable.